# Use of unassigned local variable please

Tags: c#

I created much for loops and want to put
value from a int to a string.

```
String strasze = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[straszeint].Value.ToString();
String stadt = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[stadtint].Value.ToString();
land = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[landint].Value.ToString();

hersteller = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString();
kundennummer = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[kundennummerint].Value.ToString();
haendler = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[haendlerint].Value.ToString();
```

Here is a example for loop:

```
int landint;

for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (datagridview.Columns[i].Name.Equals(landname))
    {
        landint = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

What is wrong? It shows me the error on
`straszeint`,
`stadtint`,
`landint`

//EDIT

```
int straszeint;

for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (datagridview.Columns[i].Name.Equals(straszennamen))
    {
        straszeint = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you define and initialize `straszeint`?

Comment: I edited the thread

Comment: no already looked at it

Comment: You may have already looked at the marked duplicate, but it seems you didn't fully understand the information there. It directly addresses this issue of a variable being "not definitely assigned", as in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because *Compiler is smarter than a developer*

You should Initialize the local variables before accessing their values, In your case there may be changes for skipping the iteration of the loop, or the condition inside the loop will evaluate to false in all iteration. and you are using the value (say `straszeint`) after the iterations.

Compiler expecting such situations that's why it showing such errors.

You can simply solve this by initializing the variable either with `0` or any other value that's up to you.

```
int straszeint=-1;

for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Columns.Count; i++)
{
   if (datagridview.Columns[i].Name.Equals(straszennamen))
   {
     // Let it is false for all iterations
     straszeint = i;
     break;
   }
}
// straszeint will be -1 here if the condition is false for all iteration
if(straszeint!=-1)
{
   //Proceed with the action
}
```

**Updates :** Why should we initialize with `-1` instead for `0`

The `.Cells` will follows the `0` based indexing, So it will give the First cell value even if the condition evaluates to false.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Comment: "straszeint will be zero here if the condition is false for all iteration" Wrong. It could also be the first column...

Comment: This is because int32 is not a nullable type right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman : Well, I agree with your point. But there is nothing wrong with that sentence. the value of `straszeint` will be `0` there, hence `strasze` will be the value in the first cell. Hope that I'm right.

Comment: @downrep_nation, no because it is not initialized. Method variables have to be initialized. This would be true for an object too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it is possible `straszeint` is never assigned a value. Assume what happens if `datagridview.Columns.Count` is 0, or there is no column matching the name. Then `straszeint` is never set to a value.

The compiler doesn't know what you know, so it just checks all paths and sees if there is a possible problem with an unset variable.

The easiest thing to do here is to set the variable to some arbitrary number and check that later:

```
int straszeint = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Columns.Count; i++)
    ...

if (straszeint == -1)
{
    throw new Exception("Column 'straszennamen' could not be found!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!